# Orbeon Repeat Grid Issue Dropdown Issue

Tags: xpath, orbeon, xforms

In my Repeat Grid I have 
1. First Dropdown 
2. Second Dropdown 
3. Input Area

When I select value from First Dropdown, data of Second Dropdown will be loaded. (I'm using **On Value Change** Action)

When I click on Plus (+) the value of Second Dropdown of First Row changes!

Similarly if I change any row First Dropdown, the values getting bounded for all the Second Dropdowns. Whatever I selected initially will be reloaded again!

Is this the bug in Orbeon or is there a way to load them differently?

Comment: Is this with a form you created with Form Builder? How are you populating the second dropdown when the value in the first one changes? Are you using an action for that? What version of Orbeon Forms are you on?

Comment: @avernet, 
1. Yes in the from the Form Builder
2. Yes 
3. I'm using "Value Change or Form Load"
4. Orbeon 4.8.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was the behavior prior to [Orbeon Forms 2016.1](http://blog.orbeon.com/2016/04/orbeon-forms-20161.html). You can read more details in [issue #1770](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/1770). You can consider upgrading to Orbeon Forms 2016.1, or using the [Dynamic Data Dropdown control](http://doc.orbeon.com/form-runner/component/dynamic-data-dropdown.html) as a workaround.

Comment: Upgrading to Orbeon 2016.2 solved the solved, Thank Erik, I appreciate your quick response.